# TFS2015 Visual Studio Test: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, mstest, tfs-2015, vstest

I have an "old" XAML Build Definition, made in Visual Studio; which builds a solution and following runs unit tests.
Now I've tried to make the same in the new TFS 2015 web surface.
I've created a build task, following Visual Studio Test.

But now the Test-Task exit with code 1 and gives me a lot of 
"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly" errors.
And also "Warning: MSTestAdapter failed to discover tests in class ..."

All the DLLs are where they have to be, the new definition has the same directory structure like the old one, but the test-task says there are missing assemblys.

Any ideas?

Update:
No, I still have the same error messages:

```
Warning: Unable to load types from the test source 'J:\xyz-Tests.dll'. Some or all of the tests in this source may not be discovered. If you are running unit tests for Windows Store apps and referencing custom WinMD type then please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238340 for more info. Error details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'xyz_Commons, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'xyz_Processing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'xyzCommons, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Did the test project create in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: starain-MSFT, yes it did.

Comment: What's the result after trying Andy's solution?

Answer (score 0):

This should exactly be the issue mentioned in below article, please try following the workaround to fix it:

[Running Coded UI Tests built using Visual Studio 2013 with Team Foundation Server 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sathar/2016/08/01/running-coded-ui-tests-built-using-visual-studio-2013-with-team-foundation-server-2015/)

**Test execution is failing in this scenario because test execution
engine is not able to resolve the old version binaries while executing
tests in a 14.0 environment (TFS 2015).**

So, you need to update the projects to reference the new versions of the assemblies (VS 2015 in this scenario) using the assembly bindings in the test projects config file.

> **As a workaround** to this issue, add an ‘app.config’ file to your
> solution (See how to add app.config
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms184658.aspx) and update the
> contents of the file with the shared on [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AFEpTqldDgdPWew&cid=F212DE9FAAC1FC3F&id=F212DE9FAAC1FC3F%215027&parId=F212DE9FAAC1FC3F%215026&action=locate) . The updated
> configuration files contain assembly redirects from version 12.0 to
> 14.0, which will make sure that the test agent machine is able to resolve the framework assemblies. Check-in the updated configuration
> file into the source control repository and run the BDT scenario once
> again. The tests should run fine this time.   If the test execution
> again throws an error complaining version mismatch for some other
> assembly, add the assembly to the app.config file and retry.

You can also reference this article :
http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2015/10/01/tfs-2010-to-2015-upgrade-codedui-feature-test-builds/

Comment: @Chris Roeder Have you resolved your issue by above workaround?

Comment: @ChrisRoeder PublicKeyToken = null tells you that the CLR is looking for the unsigned assembly. Since you signed them, that's not going to work well and this kaboom is expected.

You will have to rebuild the program so it uses the updated signed assembly and embeds the non-null PublicKeyToken into the manifest. You may have to remove the existing assembly reference and add it back, it isn't clear from the question whether you built the program using an unsigned copy.

Use the Fuslogvw.exe utility if you still have trouble.

Comment: I've removed the references and add it again. Same problem... When I run the fuslogvw with the old definition the assemlys have also the public token null but it works without any problem. It seems that the  testagent (vstest.console.exe) has problems to find the assemblys. But when I run the same tests with the old definition and the old testagent (vstest.executionengine.x86.exe) it's working...

Comment: it seems that the two different testadapter are looking at different folders for the dll. The vstest.executionengine.x86.exe ist looking in the right bin folder, but the vstest.console.exe is looking in the wrong folder for the assemblies. How comes?

Comment: @ChrisRoeder Please check if you have updated all the reference to redirect  the new versions of the assemblies.

Comment: I've checked that. It seems, that vstest.console.exe ist looking in the testfolder ("I:/Builds/1/TestResults/Deploy_MSGP01743$ 2017-08-09 09_33_29/Out/") for the DLL. Is it possible to set the working folder, or to copy the needed files to the testfolder before the tests starts?